# Using .find looking between two values

Tags: vba

I am working on bank reconciliation worksheet and American Express takes out their credit card fees on a daily basis. On our worksheet we assume a 3.1% cost daily so if total AX revenue was $100 we would be expecting $96.9. The actual amount deposited will vary from that amount but almost never more than 1%. I'm trying to create a code that will look for a value between 96.9 * 1.01 & 96.9 & 99. Here is what I have so far. I'm getting an error with what I'm putting in the .find(what:>findstring3 &

Sub CreditCardRec()

```
For i = 1 To 200

Windows("4110 Bank Rec 112100.xlsm").Activate
            findstring = Sheets("button").Cells(i, 30).Value
                If Trim(findstring) <> "" Then
                    findstring2 = findstring * 1.01
                    findstring3 = findstring * 0.99
                    With Sheets("Amex").Range("N:N")
                        Set rng = .Find(what:>findstring3 & <findstring2, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                            searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
                        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                            Application.Goto rng, True
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                            ActiveCell.Value = findstring
                        End If
                    End With
                End If

            Next i
```

Comment: If i understand you want, in sheet AMEX column N to loop  each cell in this column see if the value is between findstrin1 and findstring2. What i dont get it is what you want to do if found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I ended up change it to the following code which seems to be working perfectly.                                     Windows(file2).Activate
                findstring = Sheets("button").Cells(i, 30).Value
                    If Trim(findstring) <> "" Then
                        For j = 12 To 49
                        findstring2 = findstring * 1.01
                        findstring3 = findstring * 0.99
                        findstring4 = Sheets("Amex").Cells(j, 16).Value
                        findstring5 = Sheets("Amex").Cells(j + 1, 16).Value
                        findstring6 = Sheets("Amex").Cells(j + 2, 16).Value
                        findstring7 = Sheets("Amex").Cells(j, 16).Value + Sheets("Amex").Cells(j + 1, 16).Value
                        findstring8 = Sheets("Amex").Cells(j, 16).Value + Sheets("Amex").Cells(j + 1, 16).Value + Sheets("Amex").Cells(j + 2, 16).Value
                            If findstring4 > 100 Then
                                If findstring4 < findstring2 And findstring4 > findstring3 Then
                                    Sheets("Amex").Cells(j, 15).Value = findstring
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                                If findstring5 <> "" And findstring5 > 100 Then
                                    If findstring7 < findstring2 And findstring7 > findstring3 Then
                                        Sheets("Amex").Cells(j, 15).Value = findstring
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                    If findstring6 <> "" And findstring6 > 100 Then
                                        If findstring8 < findstring2 And findstring8 > findstring3 Then
                                            Sheets("Amex").Cells(j, 15).Value = findstring
                                            Exit For
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If

```
                        End If

                    Next j
                End If

            Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope is it what you are looking for:

CODE:

```
Sub test()

For i = 1 To 200

Windows("4110 Bank Rec 112100.xlsm").Activate
            findstring = Sheets("button").Cells(i, 30).Value

    If Trim(findstring) <> "" Then
        findstring2 = findstring * 1.01
        findstring3 = findstring * 0.99

        With Sheets("Amex")

            Set Rng = Sheets("Amex").Range("N" & i)

                            If Rng > findstring3 And Rng < findstring2 Then
                                Application.Goto Rng, True
                                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                                ActiveCell.Value = findstring
                            End If

            End With

    End If

Next i

  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I ended up change it to the following code which seems to be working perfectly.